# Comparing a column value with another column value + a Value not working (Better description in the body)

Tags: sql, oracle

My apologies for the title, don't know a better one.

I have the following issue, i got a complex Oracle database which requires the query to go through some hoops. For this specific query i want to see if there are any records in which Column A is Smaller then the Column B plus 0.1.

The WHERE is as following:

```
(
    COALESCE(TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_SUBSTR("Column1", '^\d+')), 0) 
    <
    (COALESCE(TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_SUBSTR("Column2", '^\d+')), 0) + 0.1)
)
```

The problem being is that it ignores the values behind the dot. For example :
Column1 = 25.4
Column2 = 25.2

This one should not be shown seeing 25.4 is larger then 25.3

If i say + 0.0 it does work correctly only showing the values where Column1 is small then column2 by nature.

If i use + 1.0 it also does it correctly, if i do +1.2 it only shows those that it jsut reats it as if it were + 1.0

Any suggestions? i'm not that experienced with Oracle, this is the only database (i sadly) have to work with using it.

Sample:

```
ID    Column1     column2
1     25.4        25.2
2     RA          16
3     22          23.1
4     21          22
5     -12.2      -12.15
6     RA          0
7     11.3792     11.3538
8     0           -.023
9     1.05        .95
```

Comment: Why regular expressions? Could you post several sample records from that table? Because, from what you said, it would be `where column_A < column_B + 0.1`

Comment: Sadly not all values are numeric, when they are not numeric they should be considered 0.

Comment: @Littlefoot  "Invalid number format model" is what i get :|

Comment: Example, please.

Comment: @Littlefoot added 4

Comment: Thank you; I posted some code. Have a look, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your sample data, see if something like this helps:

```
SQL> with test (id, col1, col2) as
  2    (select 1, '25.4', '25.2'    from dual union all
  3     select 2, 'RA'  , '16'      from dual union all
  4     select 3, '22'  , '23.1'    from dual union all
  5     select 4, '21'  , '22'      from dual union all
  6     select 5, '-12.2', '-12.15' from dual union all
  7     select 6, 'RA'  , '0'       from dual union all
  8     select 7, '11.3972', '11.3538' from dual union all
  9     select 8, '0', '-0.023'     from dual union all
 10     select 9, '1.05', '.95'     from dual
 11    ),
 12  subset as
 13    (select *
 14     from test
 15     where regexp_like(col1, '^(-)?(\d+)?(\.\d+)?$')
 16       and regexp_like(col2, '^(-)?(\d+)?(\.\d+)?$')
 17    )
 18  select *
 19  from subset
 20  where to_number(col1, '999999999.99999999', 'nls_numeric_characters = .,') <
 21        to_number(col2, '999999999.99999999', 'nls_numeric_characters = .,') + 0.1;

        ID COL1    COL2
---------- ------- -------
         3 22      23.1
         4 21      22
         5 -12.2   -12.15
         7 11.3972 11.3538
         8 0       -0.023

SQL>
```

- `subset` CTE checks whether columns contain numbers
- if so, the final `select` converts strings to numbers using format mask along with `NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS` (to distinguish thousands separators from decimal points)

If data in those columns differ from the example and cause problems, post such cases and we'll see what next.

Comment: This comes a lot closer, but there is still an issue. Running this code wil generate an error namely: "System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException (0x80131937): ERROR [22018] [Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-01722: invalid number"

This doesn't happen when i add "AND ROWNUM <= 5" to the WHERE clause limiting the output. 

I had this problem before and fixed it with the REGEX, but how can it be done in conjunction with your code (Values can be normal numbers, decimal numbers, words that should be considered 0's and blank values that should also be considered to be 0)

Comment: As I said: post such cases (edit the initial message, where you added 4 sample rows). Apparently, there's something that doesn't look like what you posted. Try to find those rows with `where NOT regexp_like(col1, '^\d+(\.\d+)?$')`.

Comment: Rownum "fixes" it just because the first 5 rows don't contain invalid values (invalid regarding code I wrote). SELECT works with the whole table so ... who knows which row is invalid? Raising rownum's value won't help (if you meant to do it that way). If you're unable to find the culprit, we could switch to PL/SQL for loop which will be way slower, but will help us find "invalid" values and fix the issue.

Comment: O no i didn't mean that as a fix, but as a way of saying "It does work as expected for the rows but not all of them. 
Also i edited the example rows with every weird one i could spot. Database is more then 25 years old and this is the first time the company wants to clean out the trash.

Comment: (Sorry, had to go offline). I modified my code, see whether there's any improvement.

Comment: No problem, it works now but do have to discard the subset idea in favor of doing it in the last where. Think this is because of the other parts of the query (the full query is about a page long) but i had isolated the problem(s) to this bit.

Answer (score 0):

This is a situation where you can use a `case` expression:

```
(case when not regexp_like(column1, '^[0-9]+[.]?[0-9]*$') 
      then null
      when not regexp_like(column2, '^[0-9]+[.]?[0-9]*$') 
      then null
      where to_number(column1) < to_number(column1)
      then 1
 end) = 1
```

I'm not usually a fan of `case` expressions in conditional expressions.  However, type conversion issues are a situation where they are useful.